# The local and average Nusselt number in a square cavity

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, flow, convection, porous-media

I am in the process of programming the local & average Nusselt number in a left vertical wall but my Matlab script gives me inappropriate values and it doesn't change with changing of Rayleigh number!!

The problem is: how to calculate and impliment the local Nusselt number in a vertical left wall of a cavity.
The expressions of the local nusselt: $\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}|_{x=0}$.

My script: using finite difference approximation with 5 points-Forward scheme ( j=1 to m+1 and i=1 )

```
Nu_loc = zeros(1,m+1);
for j=1:m+1
    Nu_loc(j) = -(-25*T(1,j)+48*T(1+1,j)-36*T(1+2,j)+16*T(1+3,j)-3*T(1+4,j))/(12*hx);   
end
```

Comment: Hello Bakizza and welcome to Physics SE. Your question regards the computational aspect of a finite differnce scheme which may be better answered in *Computational Science SE* (https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/), have you asked there?

Comment: Thank you Mr. @ZaellixA, i'll ask my question there.